# IOT PROJECT FOR NODEMCU

Tags: flutter

how can i create simulation for the following devices Arduino IDE + NodeMCU ESP8266 + Firebase and android application, soil PH sensor | NodeMCU ESP8266 send & get Data from Firebase Database. the aim is to measure the soil PH as well as displaying favourables crops and type of fertilizer that can used via android app.

Comment: is there any one who did this project?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that so so you can use cloudeFireStore as a database or RealtimeDB is there , you can use any one of them and you need to find it's end point of a collection  [refer this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database) ; if you have get that you can call from your iot device and post your data in to firebase; also connect your flutter app with firbase [refer this](https://firebase.google.com/learn/pathways/firebase-flutter) and and use some CRUD operation as you wish